# how to correctly reload fusion tables layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

i have a fusion table that changes very often.

And i have a javascript code that allows to visualize location information from database.

But how can i reload map without reloading whole page.

This is my code:

```
function initialize() {

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(60,30),
  zoom: 9,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'location',
    from: '3415835'
  }
});

layer.setMap(map); 
}
```

I've already tried this:

```
function initialize() {

//var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 40);


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(60,30),
  zoom: 9,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'location',
    from: '3415835'
  }
});



layer.setMap(map);   
refreshMap();

 }              

function refreshMap(){

 layer.setOptions({
   query: {
       select: 'location',
    from: '3415835'
    }
}); 


setTimeout('refreshMap()',5000);    
}
```

this one didn't worked.

Comment: I've found a strange situation: after adding a new marker i can see it on some zoom levels but on another i can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried throwing in a `layer.setMap(null);` in the mix, and then resetting it?

Comment: Yes. Now i think that the problem is in other thing. Take a look at my comment to question.