# Why a layer was incorrectly reloaded?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've got a problem that was discribed over there:

[how to correctly reload fusion tables layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994764/how-to-correctly-reload-fusion-tables-layer)

Briefly:
i have a fusion table that changes very often.

And i have a javascript code that allows to visualize location information from database:

Thanks everyone, i've managed to solve this thing. This is the code that works as it should:

```
var map;
var layer;
function initialize() {

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(60,30),
   zoom: 9,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });


   layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query: {
   select: 'location',
   from: '3415835'
   }
   });



   layer.setMap(map);   
   refreshMap();

}              

function refreshMap(){

  layer.setOptions({
  query: {
  select: 'location',
  from: '3415835',
   where: "location not equal to" + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString()
     }

  }); 


  setTimeout('refreshMap()',5000);    
}
```

At first t thought that my code is wrong. But after testing i discovered that layer is

being reloaded incorrectly: when new point is added i can see it on one zoom level but on

another level it dissapears. i dnon't know what's causing this: browser is cashing map or

script is wrong or smth else. Can someone help me?

Comment: I've done it: this one helped http://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_thread/thread/bc3620deda79a444

Comment: I don't see the difference between the code above and what's in the Google groups thread.  Could you explain?

Comment: I've edited my question, so now you can see the solution.

Comment: Previous code didn't work as i think because google caches queries.

Comment: Yes. That would be my guess, or perhaps your browser cache? Not sure how you'd test that, perhaps do the refresh via a button and try w/o clearing the cache and then with clear cache.