# How to reload Google maps layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener, google-fusion-tables

I want to reload Fusion Tables layer when user changes zoom level. As can be seen, I tried it but couldn't make it work.

```
var map;
var layerl0;
    function initialize() {
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(MyLat,MyLng),
            zoom:4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                    query: {
                        select: "'ColumnHeader'",
                        from: 'MyEncryptedId'
                },
                map: map
        });
        /* refresh after zooming */
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                layerl0.refresh();
    });
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What's the point of reloading the layer when the zoom changes?

Comment: I'd like to use fresh data because this FusionTable updates often with new rows.

Answer (score 2):

There is no .refresh method on [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer)

Re-run the query or destroy and recreate the FusionTablesLayer

Comment: I guess destroying and recreating the FusionTablesLayer is the best solution in this case. Could You tell me how to do that? (I'm beginner.)

Comment: `layer.setMap(null);` removes the layer, but i'd like to rebuild the whole layer and get 'real-time' data. This didn't work:
`layer.setMap(null);
 var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
 query: {
  select: "'ColumnHeader'",
  from: 'MyEncryptedId'
 },
  map: map
 })`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution. (I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996691/why-a-layer-was-incorrectly-reloaded))

Refreshes the layer in every 30 seconds:

```
var map;
var layerl0;
    function initialize() {
    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(MyLat,MyLng),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "'ColumnHeader'",
            from: 'MyEncryptedId'
        },
    });
    layerl0.setMap(map);
    refreshMap();
}
function refreshMap(){
    layerl0.setOptions({
        query: {
        select: "'ColumnHeader'",
        from: 'MyEncryptedId',
            where: "location not equal to" + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString()
        }
    }); 
    setTimeout('refreshMap()',30000);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thank you for answering @Rebecca and @geocodezip!

Answer (score 0):

This sample code is designed to swap in a different Fusion Table Layer as the user changes zoom. Perhaps it will help: 
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query_per_zoom

-Rebecca